# Trying to get property of non-object when generating a Carbon date from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When a new user registers to my app, I'm trying to create new row in the registrations table that contains a timestamp column.

I get the following error:

```
ErrorException in Registration.php line 111: Trying to get property of non-object

    in Registration.php line 111
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/app/Registration.php', '111', array('registration_time' => object(Carbon))) in Registration.php line 111
    at Registration->setRegistrationTimeAttribute(object(Carbon)) in Model.php line 2863
    at Model->setAttribute('registration_time', object(Carbon)) in Model.php line 422
```

AuthController.php (controller)

```
    $registration = Registration::create([
        'business_id' => '1',
        'registration_time' =>  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays(3)->addHours(10)->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
```

Echo of registration_time in controller

```
2016-02-12 10:00:00
```

Registration.php (model) line 111

```
public function setRegistrationTimeAttribute($registration_time)
{
    $this->attributes['registration_time'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $registration_time, \Auth::user()->timezone)->setTimezone('UTC');
}
```

What I don't understand, is that similar code works in my RegistrationTableSeeder, my model accepts this format.

```
'registration_time' =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(3)->addHours(1)->toDateTimeString(),
```

Comment: Try running just the `createFromFormat()` and dd() the Carbon object.

Comment: The error makes me think Auth::user() is null or the Carbon object is null.

Comment: yes, maybe that's because of the Auth, put `if (Auth::check())` before this line

Comment: oh good point, in fact, the new user gets created right there in that same function. I first create the new `User`, then the `Registration`. Shouldn't `\Auth::user()` exist by the time I create the Registration row? guess not because the user is not "logged in" yet?

Comment: Any ideas how I can still add a row to my Registration model even if the user is not officially logged in, without modifying my regular code in `setRegistrationTimeAttribute($registration_time)`?

Comment: If you create the user, add `Auth::login($user);` to log that user in. Then your code should work

Comment: Genius! thanks, it worked!